# Undefined reference to _sbrk in ChibiOS

Tags: embedded, sbrk, chibios

I'm using ChibiOS 3.x to write an embedded application. When compiling/linking it, I encounter an error message like this:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
```

Where is `_sbrk` defined and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_sbrk` is defined in `os/various/syscalls.c`, so ensure this file is properly compiled and linked.

Note that `_sbrk` will work correctly *if and only if* `CH_CFG_USE_MEMCORE == TRUE` (you can change that in `chconf.h`). Else, `malloc()` will always return 0 and result in an `errno` of `ENOMEM`. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32446906/2597135) for a more thorough explanation of the `ENOMEM` issue.

Also note that for embedded applications, especially when targetting high reliability, it might not be advisable to use dynamic memory allocation (of which `_sbrk` is a part of) at all (see [this detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370435/2597135))

Answer (score 4):

Added `$(CHIBIOS)/os/various/syscalls.c \` to `CSRC` in my Makefile