# malloc() always returns NULL in ChibiOS

Tags: embedded, malloc, chibios

I have a [ChibiOS](http://chibios.org/) application where I'm using dynamic memory allocation via `malloc()`.

However, I observed that 100% of the time I call `malloc()`, it returns `NULL`. I have confirmed that:

- The microcontroller memory is not full
- The error also occurs for size-1 malloc calls, so the memory chunk size is not the cause of the issues.
- `errno` is always `ENOMEM` after the `malloc()` call

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the definition of `_sbrk` in `os/various/syscalls.c`, you can clearly see that it always returns a `ENOMEM` error if `CH_CFG_USE_MEMCORE == FALSE`.

Unless you set `CH_CFG_USE_MEMCORE = TRUE` in `chconf.h`, the ChibiOS core memory manager is disabled completely and `_sbrk` and other memory-related functions are only included in the object files so no linking errors occur.

In order to properly configure ChibiOS correctly, ensure that the following is set in `chconf.h`:

```
#define CH_CFG_USE_MEMCORE                  TRUE
```

In order to avoid running into reliability issues, you might want to use [memory pools](http://chibios.sourceforge.net/html/group__pools.html) or alternative algorithms instead where possible. See [this detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370435/2597135) for a description why `malloc()` is often a bad idea on embedded systems (it's actually forbidden in most embedded coding standards entirely).